# JSON Jackson Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to load a class from JSON using annotations.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, even with a stack trace that seems pretty clear in its messaging.

Here's the JSON I want to deserialize:

```
{
    "baseUrl" : "http://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/",
    "key" : "a-valid-key",
    "responseFormat" : {
        "type" : "json",
        "handlerClass" : "JsonResponseFormatHandler"
    }
}
```

Basic class structure with details omitted:

```
public final class OpenCageConfiguration {

    @JsonProperty(BASE_URL)
    private String baseUrl;

    @JsonProperty(KEY)
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty(RESPONSE_FORMAT)
    private ResponseFormat responseFormat;

    public class ResponseFormat {

        @JsonProperty(TYPE)
        private String type;

        @JsonProperty(HANDLER_CLASS)
        private ResponseFormatHandler handler;
    }
}
```

ResponseFormatHandler class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = ResponseFormat.HANDLER_CLASS)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(JsonResponseFormatHandler.class) })
public interface ResponseFormatHandler {

    public OpenCageResponseWrapper handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws GeocodingException;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'handlerClass' that is to contain type id  (for class com.company.opencage.response.ResponseFormatHandler)
    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.company.opencage.config.OpenCageConfiguration["responseFormat"]->com.company.opencage.config.ResponseFormat["handlerClass"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:216)
```

---

**Solution** (thanks to @Darth Vader) Here's the format I ended up going with:

```
{
   ...
    "responseFormat" : {
        "type" : "json",
        "handler" : {
            "class" : "JsonResponseFormatHandler"
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = ResponseFormat.CLASS)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(JsonResponseFormatHandler.class) })
public interface ResponseFormatHandler {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you want to map from a String ("JsonResponseFormatHandler") to an object (ResposneFormatHandler), you will need to write a custom deserializer that knows how to make a ResponseFormatHandler from a string.

Comment: i thought that's the entire purpose of `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` - javadocs even say "used for configuring details of if and how type information is used, to preserve information about actual class of Object instances. necessarily for polymorphic types, may also be needed to link abstract declared types and matching concrete implementation"

Comment: yes, but in that case your JSON needs to be `"handlerClass" : {"type": "JsonResponseFormatHandler"}` or something similar to that.

Comment: that doesn't work either, and i get the same exception

Comment: the handlerClass value is a string value in the json.  if you want it to set the ResponseFormatHandler handler variable to the class named in the handlerClass value, you will need to create it yourself.

Comment: @liltitus27 Do you need `ResponseFormat` object and will `ResponseFormatHandler` inside `OpenCageConfiguration` work for you?